# Laravel how to use the results of a collection

Tags: php, collections, laravel

I'm using laravel 4 to interrogate a database and I'm unsure how to use the results effectively. BAsically I want to be able to add up the totals by type for each sale and assign each type to a variable unique to the product type.

My query is as follows:

```
$sales_group = DB::table('items')
                ->select(DB::raw("products.type, sum(items.sub_total) as sub_total"))
                ->join('products','products.id','=','items.product_id')
                ->where('invoice_id','=',$receipt->invoice_id)
                ->groupBy('products.type')
                ->get();
```

products being list of products and items table being the items/products attached to a sales invoice.

This, depending on the invoice will create a collection? that contains the product type and the total of all sales matching the product type in that invoice.

The collection has this structure:

```
    array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[683]
      public 'type' => string 'Buggy' (length=5)
      public 'sub_total' => string '20.00' (length=5)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[684]
      public 'type' => string 'Green Fee' (length=9)
      public 'sub_total' => string '54.00' (length=5)
```

I then want to assign each result to a variable to use later for example with the collection above the variables `$buggy` and `$greenFee`

How can I do this efficiently? I've tried to use `where()` on the collection such as:

```
$greenFees = $sales_group->where('type','=','Green Fee')
                 ->first();
```

I removed `get()` from the original query but I couldnt then get the value of the next result.

Should I look at changing the query?

Is there a method I can use to make assignment easier?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the collection inside an foreach loop.